npm live-server issue with updating simple CSS file
I have this very simple HTML file with a seperate CSS. It's the most basic code (there is no error in the code i can guarantee that). When I go in VS Code and type in the terminal "live-server" then the live-server starts normally and it seems to work fine when I edit my HTML page ( it refreshes the page after I save my HTML with ctrl + S). But when I try to update my CSS and save it, the page wont update the CSS changes. They get only updated when I update the .HTML file as well, which is not the expected behavior and annoying. Inside the Terminal in VSC everything looks normal when I change anything:
"Change detected C:\Users\Workstation#\Documents\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\04-HTML-CSS\index.html
CSS change detected C:\Users\Workstation#\Documents\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\04-HTML-CSS\style.css".
I looked in the Console in Chrome and it returns me this Error when updating the CSS with live-server:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
at refreshCSS (http://127.0.0.1:8080/:45:11)
at socket.onmessage (http://127.0.0.1:8080/:59:40)
This error doesn't occur when I update the HTML. But as I said, when I update the CSS and then the HTML too, then the CSS changes will be visible.
I tried to change live-server settings in VSC, but seems like they don't apply to node.js live-server but only to the live-serve from the in-built VSC extensions.
